# Feeding a load with very low impedance

Tags: power, voltage-divider, short-circuit

I need to provide a reasonable amount of power (40-50W) for a heat pillow, how should I design the power supply circuit if the load (Enamel Insulated Resistance Heating Wire) is 2,5 ohm.

I can't wrap my head around how to feed such a load without getting short circuits on one hand and voltage divider taking all the power on the other hand.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 2.5 Ohm *cold* or *heated*?

Comment: "Enamel-insulated"... so the heating wires will always be used under 105-250°C? (Depending on [rating of "Enamel"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_wire): formvar, polyurethane, polyamide, polyester, etc.)

Comment: 2.5 Ohm in cold state. However I doubt that the resistance changes dramatically after heating the wire.

Comment: I don't know your device, but I'd be surprised if there wasn't a PTC involved in stabilizing the temperature. So to be on the safe-ish side, you should design the voltage/power limit for the *cold* resistance as you're doing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using a voltage divider. What you need is a mains transformer.

50W in 2.5 ohm that's 11.1 V, 4.5A.

So I would get a mains transformer with an output of 12 V AC, of at least 5 A so 60 W or 60 VA. Also use **THICK** wires from the transformer to your load. Look at the wires in the transformer, about that thick when they're solid so for stranded cable you need something even thicker.

Comment: This seems like a good solution, if I understand things correctly the transformer factor will be 230/11.1=20.72 which means that the load considered from primary side will be 2.5*(20.72)^2 = 429.32 Ohm, which can be fed from the net without problems.

Comment: You do not have to worry about the transformation factor. As long as you get a transformer for 230 - 240 V input and 12 V output for the correct power (60 W or more, so an 80 W or 100W transformer is OK as well) then this will work. The power drawn from the mains will be the power going into your load plus the power lost in the transformer. If you get a good quality transformer, these losses will be small.

Answer (score 1):

At 2.5 Ohm, 10 V will give you 4 A and 40 W.

If you want 50 W, you need 11.18 V which will give you 4.47 A.

So maybe use a 12 V power supply that is able to deliver 4.5 A or (preferably) more?